# How is CIL used to make network / http requests?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, .net-assembly, cil

I can see a list of CIL instructions here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions

My understanding is that CIL is run in the CLR. However, I can't see how any of these instructions can be used to make a http request (which is obviously possible in the CLR).

None of the codes seem to be about getting outside information.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to understand how abstraction works. Computers can't really do anything but add, subtract, multiply, divide, and movery numbers around. It's not the CLR that does the Web request, but rather thousands of instructions in a base class library.

Comment: There is no "make HTTP request" command in Intel/AMD processors also. So no one actually can make HTTP requests. Ever. Sorry. You have to use Blackberry because we don't know if they even have CPU :)

Comment: "How can CIL obtain outside information" is a good question on its own. Perhaps this can be reworded to look better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither does it have instructions for creating files. You have a point in observing that with plain CIL, some tasks simply cannot be done. Opening sockets, writing to disk, drawing on the screen etc. are tasks that can neither be done by a single CIL instruction, nor decomposed fully into these instructions.

x86 assembly code has no instructions to play a sound using the PC Speaker, but it obviously can be done using it (not a complete example):

```
mov al, 0x36
out 0x43, al
mov ax, 11931
out 0x40, al
mov al, ah
out 0x40, al
```

Here, the [`out`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html) can be used to write a value to a CPU-specific port. This is a way to communicate with the "outside world". In this case, the CPU runs and interprets the code as best as it can, and it simply understands what the port numbers mean. It may communicate with a serial port, or simply change some voltage somewhere, but at this point, we meet the hardware, so there are no "instructions" here anymore, just electricity.

CIL doesn't have an `out` opcode, because that would be very unsafe and unverifiable. Instead (this is probably what you are asking for), it has code implementation attributes for methods to specify where to look for the implementation of a particular method.

> ImplAttr ::= …
>   | cil
>   | native
>   | runtime
>
> These attributes are mutually exclusive; they specify the type of code the method contains.
>
> **cil** specifies that the method body consists of cil code. Unless the method is declared **abstract**, the body of the method shall be provided if **cil** is used.
>
> **native** specifies that a method was implemented using native code, tied to a specific processor for
>   which it was generated. **native** methods shall not have a body but instead refer to a native method that
>   declares the body. Typically, the PInvoke functionality of the CLI is used to refer to a native method.
>
> **runtime** specifies that the implementation of the method is automatically provided by the runtime and is primarily used for the methods of delegates.
>   *(ECMA-335)*

Method marked with `cil` shall have the body consisting of CIL opcodes, `native` shall indicate that the body is in native instructions located somewhere, and `runtime` leaves the task of executing the method to the runtime. The `call` opcode is used to call these methods, as usual.

An example of such a method:

```
.method assembly hidebysig static pinvokeimpl("kernel32.dll" autochar lasterr winapi bestfit:off) 
    bool  DeleteFile(string path) cil managed preservesig
{
}
```

For some reason, ildasm displays `cil managed` which is in direct conflict with `pinvokeimpl` according to ECMA-335. It should be `native unmanaged`, and I am not sure why ildasm shows this instead.

The mechanisms of calling external methods are P/Invoke, QCall, and FCall. Good information about them can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/0c88c2e67260ddcb1d400eb6adda19de627998f5/Documentation/mscorlib.md#calling-from-managed-to-native-code). This is the only legit way defined for a CIL code to interact with the system or runtime.

Answer (score 5):

> What am I missing?

Your chain of logic goes like this:

- All CLR methods of all types are implemented with a sequence of CIL instructions
- CIL instructions can only perform certain tasks
- Some tasks require combinations of instructions not found in CIL.
- Therefore some tasks are impossible in a CLR method.

You then note that the conclusion is wrong, and correctly note that one of the steps in that chain of logic must be wrong.

The wrong one is the first one. There is no requirement that a method be implemented by a hunk of CIL that is then jitted into native code. In particular a C# method marked with the `extern` modifier is implemented by transferring control to the (presumably unmanaged code) DLL mentioned in the declaration.  Thus, code written in other languages that does stuff outside of the management of the CLR can be called from a program running under the CLR.